# Передать значения ширины и высоты объекта перед показом Activity в переменные

Tags: android, kotlin

На экране у меня FrameLayout и LinerLayout. Во FrameLayout я хочу разместить в определенном месте какой-либо объект. Например, картинку. Ее расположение зависит от размера контейнера. Для размещения картинки мне необходимо вычислить ширину и высоту FrameLayout. Если я пытаюсь узнать ширину и высоту FrameLayout в методе onCreate(), то получаю значения 0. Ведь у нас экран еще не нарисовался.

Если я пытаюсь узнать ширину и высоту FrameLayout используя метод onResume(), то тоже получаю 0. Здесь я не совсем понял, почему возвращаются 0.

На данном ресурсе я нашел код, который получает ширину и высоту нужного мне объекта, но возникла проблема, как передать эти значения в другие переменные, чтобы использовать их там, где мне необходимо.

Я создал глобальные переменные, и в них передаю значения ширины и высоты, но как только метод заканчивает работу, значения опять обнуляются.
Мой код

```
// Объявил ДО класса MainActivity
    
            var elementHeight = 0
            var elementWidth = 0

// Эти методы уже в классе MainActivity
    
            override fun onResume() {
                super.onResume()
                countWidthHeight()
            }
        
            fun countWidthHeight() {
                val flayerLayout = binding.container
                flayerLayout.getViewTreeObserver()
                    .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : OnGlobalLayoutListener {
                        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                            flayerLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
        // Здесь ширина и высота вычисляются правильно
                            elementHeight = flayerLayout.height //height is ready
                            elementWidth = flayerLayout.width
                        }
                    })
            }
        
            fun viewHeightWidth() {
        // а здесь oneHeight и oneWidth уже равны 0 хотя им передаются значения глобальных переменных
                val oneHeight = elementHeight
                val oneWidth = elementWidth
            }
```

Подскажите, что я делаю неправильно. Kotlin и Android начал изучать не так давно.

Comment: А где вы вызываете функцию viewHeightWidth?

Comment: В классе MainActivity. Но я хочу использовать эти глобальные переменные где угодно (в идеале)

Comment: Я думаю вы используете переменные до того как вызывается функция countWidthHeight. Сложно точно сказать не имея кода вызова

Comment: Не совсем понял про код вызова. Я вызываю метод viewHeightWidth() из метода onResume(). И в методе viewHeightWidth() переменные elementHeight и elementWidth уже равны 0. Хотя они глобальные. И я им присваивал значения в методе countWidthHeight(). Переменные глобальные, то есть они должны были сохранить свои значения. Правильно? Или я где то путаюсь? Метод onResume() у нас выполняется как раз перед тем, как появляется экран и мы можем начинать работать с нашим приложением.

Comment: Проще говоря, я хочу, чтобы в переменных oneHeight и oneWidth у меня был не 0, а значения oneWidth  и flayerLayout.width

Comment: Переменные не обнуляются самопроизвольно - если они равны `0`, значит вы обращаетесь к ним раньше, чем им что-то присваивается.  Нужно вызывать логику, которая требует эти значения из самого колбека, если он вообще для этого подходит. Но мне кажется лучше наследовать класс контейнера, чьи размеры вам нужны, переопределить в нём метод, сигнализирующий об изменении размеров и в этом методе пересчитывать расположение содержимого.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запустив Вашу программу, убедился в своих мыслях.
Как я выяснил в комментариях, `viewHeightWidth()` запускается из метода `onResume()`.

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    countWidthHeight()
    viewHeightWidth()
}
```

1. Мы вызвали функцию `countWidthHeight()`, добавили `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` (Ещё раз повторю, мы ТОЛЬКО добавили его, т.е. в данный момент сам листенер ещё не вызывался)
2. Дальше по порядку идет вызов функции `viewHeightWidth()`, которая использует глобальные переменные, которые не успели поменяться, т.е равны **0**.

**2 Способа решить вашу проблему**

**Первый способ:**

Сделать вызов `viewHeightWidth()`, внутри `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener`.

```
 fun countWidthHeight() {
                val flayerLayout = binding.container
                flayerLayout.getViewTreeObserver()
                    .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : OnGlobalLayoutListener {
                        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                            flayerLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                            elementHeight = flayerLayout.height 
                            elementWidth = flayerLayout.width
                            viewHeightWidth()
                        }
                    })
            }
```

**Второй способ:** Избавьтесь от `OnGlobalLayoutListener` и используйте `View.post` ([документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#post(java.lang.Runnable)))

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    binding.container.post {
        viewHeightWidth()
    }
}

fun viewHeightWidth() {
    val oneHeight = binding.container.height
    val oneWidth = binding.container.width
}
```

Comment: Где вы взяли что `View.post` как-то связан с отрисовкой? По-моему он просто кидает задачу в главный поток и она может выполниться раньше чем вы хотите.

Comment: @woesss для простоты понимания написал так, если человеку понадобится разобраться с тем, что он будет использовать - он прочтет. Конечно вы правы, это не отрисовка, мне наверное не следовало писать именно в таком контексте.

Comment: Я имел в виду что задача, брошенная в `post()` никого ждать не будет, а выполнится когда до неё дойдёт очередь и нет никакой гарантии что это случится **после** вызова `OnGlobalLayoutListener` или после того как размеры вью станут известны.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я сделал как в первом способе. То есть взял размеры внутри ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener, там же передал их в метод, который их использует и отрисовывает картинку. Все получилось, так как я и хотел

Comment: @docent28 Пожалуйста, если ответ помог и вопросов больше нет, нажмите на галочку рядом с ответом :)

Answer (score 0):

Для подобных задач хорошо подходит слушатель `View.OnLayoutChangeListener` : просто добавьте его к `ViewGroup`в методе `onCreate` активности.

```
    ViewGroup veiw_group = findViewById( R.id.root );
    veiw_group.addOnLayoutChangeListener( new View.OnLayoutChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange( View view, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int i4, int i5, int i6, int i7 ){
        }
    } );
```